# Change .ipa name according to build date

Tags: ios, objective-c, bash, plist

I am showing the build date and build number in About page of my app like this:

```
   NSString *details = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Build date: %@ _%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__],[self build]];
   self.versionDetails.hidden=!kShowVersionDetails;
   self.versionDetails.text = details;

-(void) build{
      return [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: (NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
}
```

Which shows like Build date: 24 Aug 2015 (1)

Now I would like to rename my .ipa according to the build date. Currently the name is Myapp.ipa and I would like to rename it to Myapp(24 Aug 2015_1).ipa.

How can I do that through a bash script so that when I archive a package it will display **Myapp(24 Aug 2015_1).ipa** instead of **Myapp.ipa**?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: cause we have to send builds to testers everyday and I don't want to rename them manually everyday

Comment: You could write a shell script to do it...

Comment: you mean after the .ipa I save it sa Myapp.ipa and then I run a script that appends to the filename?

Comment: Yeah; or I think you can specify its name when building with `xcodebuild`.

Comment: If you know how to specify the name during building can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use build version in you product name. It's really easy, especially if you use agvtool. First you need to set up your current project version and your versioning system as it's described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1827/_index.html).

Then set your product name with something like: `$(TARGET_NAME)_$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`

So you will get an ipa named: `MyApp_1.ipa`. And before your next buid, simply increment your build number by runing the following command line from the directory containing your .xcodeproj project file: `agvtool next-version -all`

Comment: Thanks almost what I wanted. how do I get the date appended to the ipa?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think the only way to get the date is to make a script but you cannot access to this value before you build your project :(